# Accessing views outside of onCreateView() method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to make a particular nested FrameLayout visible dynamically. However, i am getting `NullPointerException` when i try to access the view outside of my fragment's `onCreateView()` method. So here is my implementation.

```
private View myView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View fragmentView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.listView, container, false);
    this.myView = fragmentView;
    ...
   return fragmentView;
}

@Override
public void apiCompleted(ApiResult apiResult, HttpRequest httpRequest) {

 if(myLocationManager.hasLocation()){

    FrameLayout flayout = (FrameLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.ldrawlayout);
    flayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
 }
```

**listView.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_gray"
    tools:context=".fragment.MallListFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_malls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**rowlist.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_mallx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ldrawlayout"
    >
    ...
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**LOGCAT (onCreateView method is called first)**

```
01-15 18:40:16.905    7633-7633/? V/onCreateView METHOD CALLED﹕ onCreateView
01-15 18:40:17.280    7633-7633/? V/APICOMPLETED METHOD CALLED﹕ apiCompleted
```

Comment: everything looks fine but once try getView() instead of myView...

Comment: you don't need to store a reference to the root layout. you can call Fragments `getView()` method. But that doesn't cause the problem. Please check if id ldrawlayout is present in R.layout.listView

Comment: @aschattney R.layout.listView is a Listview so this particular framelayout is not present there. It is present in another xml which is used as a row for the list view

Comment: You get null pointer for _myView_ or _flayout_ ?

Comment: your apiCompleted method call before onCreated menthod...

Comment: I suspect that _myView_ is null in _apiCompleted()_ as well. Did you find a solution for this? I am looking for how to get the view from a method such as this.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I see the problem. You want to access the row-layout, but your listview has multiple versions of this layout, that mean you can not access the row layout from the activity, you have to do it in your listadapter or you give your single rows in the listadapter an unique id such as row.setId(row.getId + positionOfRow)

Comment: After you set the unique IDs in the getView()-Method of your adapter, you can access the rows, but the listview have to fill first and not every element is generate at the beginning.
The easier way is to move apiCompleted stuff into your adapter and arrange it there. Or what's even cooler, you add the rows when the api is finished and make them not visible/invisible. You can also add an animation for adding items to a listview and have also a nice ui experience for the user. Deal? ;)

Comment: I tried to use the getView() method for my adapter and set the view to be visible but even there i have nullptrexception

Comment: It's a litte bit confusing what you want to do. Do you want to make every single item visible after the api is completed or the complete listview?

Comment: So i like 10 items on my row of the listview. 8 appear always but 2 appear only is say a boolean value sent from the server is true. So in my adapter i have like this in my getView() method:

TextView abc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.aaa);

if(booleanValue == true){
  abc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }

Comment: Then don't search the view with an ID. Instead of searching, return the 2 views in your apiCompleted method and set them visible

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater Inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_mallx, null);

FrameLayout flayout = (FrameLayout) view .findViewById(R.id.ldrawlayout);

flayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

try this code in on apiCompleted

Comment: This doesn't give me a nullptr exception but still the layout remains invisible.

Comment: In my xml I have made the layout to be like android:visibility="gone"

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure that the onCreateView() method is called before the apiCompleted() method.

If yes, you should be able to access the view any where in your code as long as you hold the reference to it.

You can add some logs to see the order that the functions get called